# jQuery validate plug in - validating hidden elements only when visible

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form that has a "Is you billing address the same as your shipping address" field. If the user clicks the radio button "No" the hidden ul#billingAddress is shown. The fields contained in ul#billingAddress are required if it is visible, that is if the ul has display:block.

How do I write a custom addMethod for jquery validate.js that requires those only if the field is visible? This is what I have that isn't working.

```
$.validator.addMethod ("BillingSameAsShipping", function(value, element) {
   var billingFields = ['billingAddress1','billingAddress2','billingCity','billingState','bilingZip']
   if ($("#billingAddress").is('visible') && billingFields.val('') {
       return false;
   } else 
       return true;
 }, "Please fill in the required billing information" );
```

This, obviously is jacked. I need to make it work for each one that is in the var.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried making them not only invisible, but also setting them to disabled? It's just a guess, but since disabled form fields would not be transmitted anyway, I would expect that no validation happens on them.

Comment: I shouldn't have to make them disabled, I just want them to only validate when visible. Unless making them disabled is easier?

Comment: I mean making them both invisible *and* disabled. With jQuery, this is easy enough.

Comment: Yes, i know how to do that, I would rather make them required only if visible, as per my original question

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem with the visible check is this part: `.is('visible')`  it needs to be: `.is(':visible')` to use the [`:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

---

As an alternative, you can use the [`ignore` option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) to do what you want a bit easier, like this:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
  //other options
  ignore: ':hidden'
});
```

This approach lets you use the standard required rules if you want.